# Override first letter capitalization of sentences for UITextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I would like to make lowercase every first string of a sentence, that user writes into a `UITextView`.

Example

> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur adipiscing elit. phasellus et
>   tincidunt eros at faucibus orci.

There are a lot of related question for `UITextfield`, but I couldn't find any useful answers that deals with `UITextview`. Is it possible with a UITextView property or I need to check every string and make them lowercase? I've tried to set the keyboard in Interface Builder without any success.

Answer (score 4):

Check this

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

there are following you can use -

```
typedef enum : NSInteger  {
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone ,
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords ,
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences ,
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters ,
} UITextAutocapitalizationType;
```

Default is The default value for this property is UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences.

Comment: @bushiko Questions like this should start by looking at the reference documentation. You will see that `UITextView` has the same property (through `UITextInputTraits`).

Comment: Check this UITextInputTraits which supports UITextField and UITextView protocol which has autocapitalizationType

Comment: @rmaddy maybe because I'm tired or just simply missed it, but I haven't seen it [https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html] here. I've checked the "Conforms to" widget.